# How do I save a frame splitter position and restore it later?

Tags: asp.net, html, frames, onmouseup

I have a web application where the window contains a frameset with two frames split vertically. I want the web application to remember where the frame splitter line was moved to, so that the next time the page is loaded, the frame splitter is drawn at the position where it was left.

How do people normally do this?

Currently, after a user has dragged the splitter to the new position, I am trying to use the `onmouseup` event to obtain the `clientWidth` of the left frame and store the `clientWidth` in a database for later retrieval. The problem is getting the `clientWidth` of the frame during the `onmouseup` event is not returning the width of the frame at the new splitter position, rather, it is returning the width of the frame at the old position. It seems that at the `onmouseup` event, the splitter has not rendered at the new position yet, as a result, my application is not loading the page with the splitter at the last saved position.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using the `onmouseup` event, I used the `onresize` event of the frame, which gives me the position of the splitter at the new position.

Answer (score -1):

I dont know egsactly, but i'm doing something like this:

i've added a javascript code in one of the frames

```
fwidth=window.parent.document.getElementById('frameA').width;
```

after i'll save this width in cookie and restore the positions with it

---

now i'm trying to make an event like onchange but for now without success :(